# Google Sheets Array/Filter for Newest Date/Unique ID

Tags: arrays, filter, google-sheets

I have a sheet "RawCount" with Google Form results that will accumulate over time (people will make entries each week or as their raw number changes).

I need a way to compile the data to obtain the most recent entry for each individual who has entered data via the form:

[image]

This data will accumulate with new entries over the period of eight months from up to 100 or more different people.

I would like to sum the most recent entries for each individual onto another tab in the same Google Sheet that contains a scorecard.

Thanks for any help you can offer.  I think I've sprained my brain on this.

Comment: I think I may know how to do this, but am not clear enough on what you mean. What do you mean by sum the most recent entries? How many of the most recent? Is that a different sum for Fred and Barney?

Comment: So I think if A has your dates, B has your people, and C has your scores, what you want is=query(A:C,"Select max(A), B, sum(C) group by B"). That will put the most recent date for each person, the person's name, and the sum of all the person's scores. If that is what you mean, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: I need a single total comprised of each person's most recent entry. So, adding the most recent entry for Fred to the most recent entry for Barney and so forth down the list.  The formula should end with just a total sum, one number, that represents the sum of the most recent entry made by each unique person.  Hope that is more clear. So if Fred's most recent entry is 206, and Barney's most recent is 374, and Betty's most recent is 5, the formula result would be the sum: 587.